# set IP and Port in proxy in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, proxy, request, instagram

i want to send request to instagram with this address :"https://i.instagram.com"
and i want to use proxy for each request that i have send
 which one is ok?
and the uri (""https://i.instagram.com:8080"") is ok?
 if second code is ok then what is the **NetworkCredential**

```
    IWebProxy Proxya = System.Net.WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
    //to get default proxy settings
    Proxya.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

    Uri targetserver = new Uri("https://i.instagram.com:8080");
    Uri proxyserver = Proxya.GetProxy(targetserver);


    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.Proxy = Proxya;
```

second

```
    IWebProxy Proxya = System.Net.WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
    //to get default proxy settings
    Proxya.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxxx");

    Uri targetserver = new Uri("https://i.instagram.com:8080");
    Uri proxyserver = Proxya.GetProxy(targetserver);


    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.Proxy = Proxya;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take care of what you want to do.

Right now, you're telling your program to take the locally defined proxy server via `GetSystemWebProxy()`. This means that the program uses the proxy defined in your system's proxy settings.

After that you're telling the program here:

```
Uri targetserver = new Uri("https://i.instagram.com:8080");
Uri proxyserver = Proxya.GetProxy(targetserver);
```

That your proxy server is listening on `https://i.instagram.com:8080`. This should be part of your `WebRequest`.

Now `Proxya.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxxx");` simple says that your proxy server requires authentication via username and password. 
Does your proxy server allow anonymous login? If yes, then you don't need it.

But(!) I wouldn't recommend providing an open proxy.

I'd suggest you split your code into two parts:

**The Proxy code part:**

Define your proxy settings here:

```
string proxyAddress = "proxyAddress";
int proxyPort = 1337;
string proxyUser = "user";
string proxyPassword = "password";
IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(proxyAddress, proxyPort)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyUser, proxyPassword)
};
```

Or if you don't use a proxy, simple don't define one.
If you're using the proxy defined in your system's settings, then this should suffice:

```
IWebProxy proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
```

**The `WebRequest` or `HttpClientHandler` itself.**

```
string instagramAddress = "https://i.instagram.com:8080";
Uri targetserver = new Uri(instagramAddress);
// HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(targetserver);
// handler.Proxy = proxy;
request.Proxy = proxy; //Set the previously defined proxy here
```

Comment: i dont have any proxy setting on website host server.and what is the finall code

Comment: I don't know, there are some free proxies out there. Google may help you here. The question is, why you'd need one. Is there anything you're trying to achieve?

Comment: i dont have any proxy setting on website host server.and what is the finall code?

Comment: OK, then simply use a `WebRequest` without proxy.

Comment: the instagram has limit that with one IP we can only connect 5 user. my app is instagram bot for follow and unfollow so i think proxy solve this limit

Comment: can u give me a code i am confused.i never use proxy befor i just want to solve that limitation by instagram

Comment: The code is right in the answer. Every proxy server has an IP address and/or a domain name (e.g. `myTestProxy.com` and a port `1234`). This is what you need for the code. You'll find a list of free proxies, e.g. here: https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/ 
`string proxyAddress = "66.82.15.7";
int proxyPort = 88;` The first server on this list would look like above. If you don't need Authentication, simply remove this `Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyUser, proxyPassword)` I can't help you anymore, be aware that what you're doing is *against the TOS of Instagram*.

Comment: tanks and other question: for each user that connect with my app to Instagram . should i use individual proxy per user ? i mean for each user one IP and port ? or if i use one proxy with one IP an port for all user .is it pass the limitation on Instagram? which way is current ?

Comment: Right now you're using one proxy for all calls. You will not pass the limitation of Instagram this way. Yes, you should use one proxy for each user, but then you need n proxy servers for n users -> many servers with many IPs.

Comment: is that possible? if not how can i pass the limitation